# Eager macro-expansion failure: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)

Tags: advice, easy-menu, macroexpansion

I have this code:

```el
(defun make-search-sensitive-to-ifpmod-advice (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Temporary advice the search functions to make them sensitive to
`isearch-filter-predicate'"
  (let ((POINT (point)))
    (catch 'filtered
      (while (apply orig-fun args)
        (let ((B (match-beginning 0))
              (E (match-end 0)))
          ;; 1 - If all points in the region that matches the search
          ;; from the previous "search-command" meet the criteria
          ;; accepted by the filter, then the loop stops (`throw') and
          ;; returns the position `(point)`:
          (when (funcall isearch-filter-predicate B E)
            (throw 'filtered (point)))))
      ;; 2 - If the search is unsuccessful, or does not meet
      ;; the criteria accepted by the filter, then return to the
      ;; starting position and return the value `nil'.
      (goto-char POINT)
      nil)))
```

```el
(defalias 'search-forward-ifpmod
  (symbol-function 'search-forward)
  "Copy of `search-forward' function (to be) adviced to obey to
`isearch-filter-predicate'")

(advice-add 'search-forward-ifpmod
            :around
            #'make-search-sensitive-to-ifpmod-advice)

(defalias 're-search-forward-ifpmod
  (symbol-function 're-search-forward)
  "Copy of `re-search-forward' function (to be) adviced to obey to
`isearch-filter-predicate'")
(defalias 'search-forward-regexp-ifpmod 're-search-forward-ifpmod)

;; The following breaks my minor-modes definitions
(advice-add 're-search-forward-ifpmod
            :around
            #'make-search-sensitive-to-ifpmod-advice)
```

I found that this particular code snippet:

```el
(advice-add 're-search-forward-ifpmod
            :around
            #'make-search-sensitive-to-ifpmod-advice)
```

breaks my minor-modes definitions. E.g. if I evaluate the code above and later on the following code (MWE):

```el
(defun mwe-function-1 ()
  "MWE function 1"
  (interactive)
    (message "function 1 executed"))

(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter (:eval (propertize " MWE "
                              'face '(:foreground
                                      "RoyalBlue"
                                      :background
                                      "DarkGoldenrod1")))

  :keymap
  `(
    (,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . mwe-function)
    )

  (if mwe-mode
      (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
        "MWE"
        '("MWE mode"
          ;; I want the menu on mode-line only:
          :visible (not (eq (framep (selected-frame)) 'x))
          ["mwe-function-1" mwe-function-1
           :help "mwe-function 1"]
          ))
    t))
```

I get this error:

> internal-macroexpand-for-load: Eager macro-expansion failure: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)

##### Step to reproduce the error:

1. `emacs -Q`
2. Evalute the `add-advice` code
3. Evalute my minor-mode definiton

Did I make a mistake in the `add-advice` usage or is it a bug?

**Edit.** Added backtrace and my Emacs version:

- *Backtrace*

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Eager macro-expansion failure:
> (wrong-type-argumen...")   error("Eager macro-expansion failure: %S"
> (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil))
> internal-macroexpand-for-load((define-minor-mode mwe-mode "MWE mode"
> :init-value nil :lighter (:eval (propertize " MWE " 'face
> '(:foreground "RoyalBlue" :background "DarkGoldenrod1"))) :keymap
> `((,(kbd "") . mwe-function)) (if mwe-mode (easy-menu-define
> mwe-menu mwe-mode-map "MWE" '("MWE mode" :visible (not (eq ... ...))
> ["mwe-function-1" mwe-function-1 :help "mwe-function 1"])) t)) nil)
> eval-buffer()  ; Reading at buffer position 767
> funcall-interactively(eval-buffer)   command-execute(eval-buffer
> record)   execute-extended-command(nil "eval-buffer" "eval-bu")
> funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "eval-buffer"
> "eval-bu")   command-execute(execute-extended-command)

- *Emacs version*

```
emacs -version
GNU Emacs 29.2
Development version ac89b1141a26 on master branch; build date 2024-02-27.
```

Comment: FIrst step as always: make sure that `debug-on-error` is `t` and redo the problematic operation. You should now get a backtrace which you should add to your question.

Comment: @NickD  added the backtrace. Thanks.